# Having issues getting a loop to work combined with a function

Tags: c++, function, loops

Trying to get a program to prompt a user to input letters that will be converted into a phone number (which is working fine), and then prompt the user if they would like to repeat the same steps (This is where I am running into an error).  The program converst the phone number, then immediately produces the cout statements without letting the user input the cin>>repeat character.

> "Would you like to enter a phone number: Y/N "
>
> "Please enter a valid input: Y/N."

I have a cin>> between the two, as you can see in the code.  Any advice on how to get this working? Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void telephoneConverter();
int counter;
char phoneNumber;

int main()
{   
char repeat;



telephoneConverter();
   
cout << endl
     << "Would you like to enter a phone 
number: Y/N ";
    cin >> repeat;
if (repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y') {

    telephoneConverter();
}
if (repeat == 'N' || repeat == 'n') {
    cout << "Have a good day.";
}
else
    cout << "Please enter a valid input: Y/N.";

return 0;
}

void telephoneConverter()
{

cout << "\nEnter a phone number in letters 
only."
     << endl;

for (counter = 0; counter < 7; counter++) {
    cin >> phoneNumber;

    if (counter == 3)
        cout << "-";

    if ((phoneNumber >= 'A' && phoneNumber 
<= 'Z')
        || (phoneNumber >= 'a' && phoneNumber 
<= 'z'))
        switch (phoneNumber) {
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
        case 'B':
        case 'b':
        case 'C':
        case 'c':
            cout << 2;
            break;
        case 'D':
        case 'd':
        case 'E':
        case 'e':
        case 'F':
        case 'f':
            cout << 3;
            break;
        case 'G':
        case 'g':
        case 'H':
        case 'h':
        case 'I':
        case 'i':
            cout << 4;
            break;

        case 'J':
        case 'j':
        case 'K':
        case 'k':
        case 'L':
        case 'l':
            cout << 5;
            break;
        case 'M':
        case 'm':
        case 'N':
        case 'n':
        case 'O':
        case 'o':
            cout << 6;
            break;
        case 'P':
        case 'p':
        case 'Q':
        case 'q':
        case 'R':
        case 'r':
        case 'S':
        case 's':
            cout << 7;
            break;

        case 'T':
        case 't':
        case 'U':
        case 'u':
        case 'V':
        case 'v':
            cout << 8;
            break;

        case 'W':
        case 'w':
        case 'X':
        case 'x':
        case 'Y':
        case 'y':
        case 'Z':
        case 'z':
            cout << 9;
            break;
        }
 }
};
```

Comment: That switch though...

Comment: You only input `repeat` once, then if it is `Y` you do another number but never ask for `repeat` again. So when you get the test against `N` the value is still `Y` and gets rejected.

Comment: yes, I changed that also.  thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you commit entering your phone number with pressing "Enter", such that a new line will be left in the `cin` stream. This new line will then be consumed immediately by `cin >> repeat`.
To avoid this, skip/ignore any characters in the `cin` stream until (and including) a new line before reading in `repeat`:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
cin >> repeat;
```

And include `#include <limits>`...

Comment: makes sense, but the code you provided is throwing back several errors.  

https://pastebin.com/QCNitjV5